# Need changing "\" to "/" in url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

A developer abandoned a project and left me with an add-on that keeps asking for files from the directory `http://website.com/file/images\##\##.png`

The problem is the two "\" are suppose to be "/".

Everything works fine except this minor issue. Thought I come here for help?

I look at and tried to learn rewrite to fix this but it's beyond me.
I need help with this "\" issue. Is it possible to use htaccess to fix this?

Comment: The "\" vanished between the images ## ##.png

Comment: Which kind of project? Would it be safer/easier to edit that project's source?